# how to use Gmail attachment in our Application?

Tags: android, gmail

*May be I am not express what I need but here is my effort. please correct me If I am going in the wrong way*

**I got an email and there is an attachment. When I long pressed  on it  and release. I got below pop-up**

[image]

**So, My Query is :**

`How can access this attachment in my Application through Giving permission.`

**In iOS there is way that is :**

You can give permission of file extension in the application . If the extension name is present in the download file, you app icon will be display and you can use that extension file into your app.

**Please give me some direction to do this thing.**

Comment: Register a `Activity` which accepts that file extension in manifest

Comment: As An example, to accept a text file, You need to register an `Activity` with `mime-type` like `<intent-filter ><data android:mimeType="text/rtf"/></intent-filter>`. So when ever user trying to open a text file, Android System will show your app in chooser dialog

Comment: Are you send mail from your android application? and where is the attachment save while uploading?

Comment: yes, i am sending through my app and to whom I sent. If the App is Available with the another person. he will open through the App.